# Zend2 install ZendOauth module with composer

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm totally new to zend2 and would like to install the zendframework/zendoauth module.
I added the module to composer.json and installed it properly with "composer install"

**Contents of my composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "my_project_name",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "*",
        "zendframework/zendoauth": "2.0.*",
    }
}
```

This downloaded the module into vendor/zendframework/zendoauth.
I edited config/application.config and added 'ZendOauth'.

**Contents of my config/application.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'ZendOAuth'
    ),
...
```

Now when i try to access my website i get an error:

> Fatal error:
>   Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException'
>   with message 'Module (ZendOAuth) could not be initialized.'

My question is: Is there anything i missed?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ZendOAuth isn't a module, it's a library, which is why you're getting an error message when you add it to the list of modules. You just `use` the classes it supplies in your own application. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any documentation for it at the moment, but to get an idea of usage, maybe take a look at the unit tests https://github.com/zendframework/ZendOAuth/tree/master/tests/ZendOAuth

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and it makes a whole lot of sense. Feel free to post it as answer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZendOAuth isn't a module, it's a library, which is why you're getting an error message when you add it to the list of modules. You just `use` the classes it supplies in your own application.

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any documentation for it at the moment, but to get an idea of usage, maybe take a look at the unit tests https://github.com/zendframework/ZendOAuth/tree/master/tests/ZendOAuth